# Can I run low voltage wires through a wall for LED strips?

Tags: electrical, led

[image]The setup will be:

`outlet -> 24V driver -> Bluetooth connected by remote -> 16 gauge wire run through wall studs -> LED strips (about 20 feet away)`

- Is this an ok setup safety wise?
- Is it ok to run this wire through wall studs similar to how Romex™ cable is run?

I'm recessing into drywall, similar to this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KZiNcbe-so).

- Does the connection from the 16 gauge wire to the led strips need a junction box of some sort?

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this, where that could possibly fit.  This is in my basement and the ceiling will be open and painted black.

I think I have added a photo that looks similar to what I am trying to do. Instead of recessed lights like the pic I want to run led strips recessed in the drywall. The YouTube video also shows this, there is a picture of the finished product in the first few seconds. You don’t need to watch the rest

Comment: There is no link.  Just a screenshot would be sufficient rather than a video. A junction box makes it tidier.  Since its low voltage, there is probably no regulations covering it, in your area.

Comment: There most definitely _are_ regulations covering low voltage wiring in walls! They pertain more to the insulation of the wiring and how flammable and toxic the smoke is, more than junction boxes and splicing, but those are covered, too.

Comment: Additionally, pictures or screen grabs from the video would be far better than expecting others to watch a video of unknown length and unknown quality. Help us help you...

Answer (score 2):

Cable run through the wall is required to be [CL, CL2, CL3, CM, CMG, CMR or CMP rated.](https://www.cmple.com/learn/understanding-cable-jacket-ratings-cl-cm-cmr-and-cmp) *I am not affiliated with the link, which provides additional background detail on these cable ratings.* Or you can (with adequate care to not confuse the them with line voltage cables, and keeping them separated from those) use "normal" line voltage cable/wiring such as NM/B ("Romex®") but that will be 14AWG minimum.

Not just whatever random stuff, and that specifically applies to low voltage wiring installed in walls. **Not** "no regulations covering it" *as incorrectly stated in a comment.* The rated cables have passed flame testing of their insulation materials for the rated use as required by code for wires installed in the walls (or risers or plenum spaces for CMR and CMP respectively. Those ratings exceed the wall case, and plenum exceeds riser, so plenum rated cable is suitable anywhere in a building that cables are allowed to be.)

A junction box is **not required** on the low voltage side, but it can be a good idea (and does not cost much) simply because it provides a place to secure the items being connected so they are not abused.